# Magento Coupon Codes Not Working When Customer Logged In Since Failed Upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

Ever since a failed upgrade from 1.8.1 to 1.9.1 (rolled back now) coupon codes don't work for customers that are logged in. Works fine when not logged in.
I just purchased an extension that lets me set customer error codes for coupons and when logged in the error is for the 'catch all' error - ie one that has no known reason.

I am thinking that maybe the file that controls coupon application is corrupt or somehow not successfully rolled back

Does anyone know what file applies coupons in the cart and checkout so I can re-install from a fresh down of our version?

THanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a [known bug](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/67) in Magento CE 1.9.
You can try [this extension](https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix) to fix it temporarily.